# ラジオボタン型のアラートダイアログ内での選択項目をテキストビューに表示させたい

Tags: android, java, android-studio, android-fragments

はじめて質問させていただきます。 
Android開発及びJava初心者です。

「ボタンをクリックすると、ラジオボタン型のアラートダイアログが表示され項目を選択すると 
MainActivity内のTextViewに選択した項目の内容が表示される」という内容のプログラムを作りたいと思っております。

以下のコードで実行するとアラートダイアログが表示された後項目を選択したタイミングでエラーが発生してしまいます。

ネットで検索などをして調べてみたのですが、原因がわかりませんでした。 
どなたか原因を教えていただけたらと思います。

よろしくお願いします。

ソースコード 
↓↓↓

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.app.Dialog; 
import android.app.DialogFragment; 
import android.app.ProgressDialog; 
import android.content.DialogInterface; 
import android.os.CountDownTimer; 
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.TextView; 

import java.util.List; 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{ 

    @Override 
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        findViewById(R.id.ok).setOnClickListener(this); 
         findViewById(R.id.progress).setOnClickListener(this); 
         findViewById(R.id.single).setOnClickListener(this); 
         findViewById(R.id.multi).setOnClickListener(this); 
         findViewById(R.id.edit).setOnClickListener(this); 
     } 

    @Override 
     public void onClick(View v) { 
         String[] items = {"A","B","C","D"}; 
         int id = v.getId(); 
         if(id == R.id.ok){ 
             OkDialog.showDialog(this,"OKダイアログ","ボタンを押した"); 
         }else if(id == R.id.progress){ 
             MyProgressDialog.showDialog(this,"プログレスダイアログ",100); 
         }else if(id == R.id.single){ 
             SingleDialog.showDialog(this,"シングルチョイスダイアログ",items); 
         }else if(id == R.id.multi){ 
             MultiDialog.showDialog(this,"マルチチョイスダイアログ",items); 
         }else if(id == R.id.edit){ 
             EditDialog.showDialog(this,"エディットダイアログ","テキストを入力"); 
         } 
     } 

//シングルチョイスダイアログ 
    public static class SingleDialog extends DialogFragment{ 
         //表示 
        public static void showDialog(Activity activity,String title,String[] items){ 
             SingleDialog singleDialog = new SingleDialog(); 
             Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
             args.putString("title",title); 
             args.putStringArray("items",items); 
             singleDialog.setArguments(args); 
             singleDialog.show(activity.getFragmentManager(),"singleDialog"); 
         } 

        //生成 
        @Override 
         public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) { 
             final String[] items = getArguments().getStringArray("items"); 

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
             builder.setTitle(getArguments().getString("title")); 
             builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                 @Override 
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                     MainActivity activity = new MainActivity(); 
                     ((TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(items[which] + "が選択されました"); 
                 } 
             }); 
             builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null); 
         return builder.create(); 
         } 
     }
```

エラーメッセージ 
↓↓↓

```
 04-12 00:25:14.379 31269-31269/sample.dialog E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
                                                                Process: sample.dialog, PID: 31269 
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884) 
                                                                    at sample.dialog.MainActivity$SingleDialog$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:136) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:958) 
                                                                    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299) 
                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113) 
                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911) 
                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 04-12 00:25:16.219 31269-31269/sample.dialog I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31269 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
    ((TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(items[which] + "が選択されました");
}
```

原因はこの部分ですね。

`Activity`をユーザーが`new`する状況はまずないと考えてください。`MainActivity`を`new`しても、そのタイミングではまだ`View`は作られていませんので、`findViewById()`の結果は`null`になります。（`onCreate()`で`setContentView()`したタイミングで、初めて`View`が生成されます）

このコードの意図は、「呼び出し元の`Activity`の`TextView`に、選択した結果を反映させたい」だと思いますので、

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(items[which] + "が選択されました");
}
```

`getActivity()`を用いれば期待した動作になると思います。ただし、これはあまり良いコードであるとは言えません。

Android Studioで`Fragment`を新規作成するとき、コールバック用のインターフェースの作成を選択できると思いますが、このとき生成されたテンプレートは`Activity`と`Fragment`をどのように連携させるのかを理解する良いサンプルだと思いますので、参考にしてみてください。